# fill a range until a certain value is reached

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way in vba to fill a range until a certain value is reached?

For example, I want to fill column A with dates starting from the value in cell B1 (Let’s say 1/1/2014) till it reaches the value in cell C1 (Let’s say 1/15/2014) stepping one day.

Is this possible please?

Thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my proposition, just put the dates in B1 and C1 cells and run "Dates" macro.

```
Sub Dates()

Dim startdate As Date
Dim enddate As Date
Dim row As Double

startdate = Range("B1").Value
enddate = Range("C1").Value
row = 0

Range("A1").Select
Do Until DateAdd("d", 1, startdate) = enddate + 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(row, 0).Value = DateAdd("d", 1, startdate)
    startdate = startdate + 1
    row = row + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Sub DateFiller()
    For i = 2 To Rows.Count
        Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i - 1, 1).Value + 1
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(1, 2).Value Then Exit Sub
    Next i
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

this version matches the request:

```
Sub DateFiller()
    Cells(1, 1).Value = Cells(1, 2).Value
    For i = 2 To Rows.Count
        Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i - 1, 1).Value + 1
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(1, 3).Value Then Exit Sub
    Next i
End Sub
```